# Find the TYPE of any JSON element using its JSON Schema and Jackson Schema parser library in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, jsonnode

I am trying to find the `type` of any element within the JSON Schema using the most memory efficient and high-performance approach. However, after reaching a certain point I am a bit stuck and running out of ideas so hoping to get an answer here:

Basically, I have a `List: jsonPath` which will consist of the element along with its parent whose type I need to identify from the `Json Schema` that I have. For parsing the `Json Schema` I am using the `Java Jackson Library`. I am able to get all the elements and able to find its type but during the comparison, I am a bit confused.

Following is the code I have so far:
As we can see I have the `jsonPath` as `"food", "Ingredients", "ingredient"` which means that I need to find the `type` of last element `ingredient` and others are its parents. The program should return `type` as `array`. Similarly, if I pass any other elements in the `jsonPath array` such as just `food` or `price` then it should check for corresponding parents and their children then finally should return its type. I have used the `Stack elements` just for reference purposes you can ignore that.

I can try to add multiple `if` conditions at every stage and get the element type. However, I am trying to find a simple and better way rather than using complex nested if's. It should be possible to do in a much simple way but nothing is clicking at the moment for me.

```
 public class JsonElementLocator {

     private final JsonNode outerNode;
     private static JsonElementLocator _instance;

     // Default constructor to get the content and store in the root
     private JsonElementLocator() throws IOException {
         final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
         final JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(JsonElementLocator.class.getClassLoader().getResource("testJSON.json"));
         outerNode = root.path("definitions");
     }

     // Method to create a Object instance of current class
     private static synchronized JsonElementLocator getInstance() throws IOException {
         if (_instance == null) {
             _instance = new JsonElementLocator();
         }
         return _instance;
     }

     // Method called by other application to get the element Type
     public static Optional < String > locate(List < String > elementPath) throws IOException {

         JsonElementLocator cl = getInstance();
         JsonNode rootNode = cl.outerNode;
         recurse(rootNode, new Stack < String > ());
         return Optional.empty();
     }

     // Method called recursively to get the element Type from JSON Schema
     private static Optional < String > recurse(JsonNode rootNode, Stack < String > elements) {

         // Loop through each Object in Root Node
         for (JsonNode childNode: rootNode) {

             // Check if childNode is of Object type
             if (childNode.path("type").toString().contains("object")) {

                 elements.push(childNode.get("title").toString());

                 // Call recurse method for the subsequent objects
                 recurse(childNode.path("properties"), elements);

                 elements.pop();

             } else if (childNode.path("type").toString().contains("array")) {
                 // Check if childNode is of Array type and call its elements

                 for (JsonNode ccNode: childNode.path("items")) {
                     final String def = ccNode.toString().contains("definitions") ? ccNode.toString().replace("\"", "").replaceAll("#/definitions/",
                         "") : null;

                     // Find the element from the root
                     if (def != null) {
                         final JsonNode defInfo = _instance.outerNode.get(def);

                         // Call recurse method for definition elements
                         recurse(defInfo.path("properties"), elements);
                     }

                 }

             } else {

                 System.out.println(String.join("/", elements));
                 // Check if childNode is of normal type
             }
         }
         return Optional.empty();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         List < String > jsonPath = new ArrayList < String > (List.of("food", "Ingredients", "ingredient"));
         locate(jsonPath);
     }

 }
```

Following is the complete `Json Schema` that I am trying to parse:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Welcome2",
    "definitions": {
        "Welcome2": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "hotelName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "food": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Food"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "food",
                "hotelName"
            ],
            "title": "Welcome2"
        },
        "Food": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "price": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "calories": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "integer"
                },
                "ingredients": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/Ingredients"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "calories",
                "description",
                "ingredients",
                "name",
                "price"
            ],
            "title": "Food"
        },
        "Ingredients": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "ingredient": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "ingredient"
            ],
            "title": "Ingredients"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of things I was able to do it. Adding the code as answer as it can help someone in the future who is trying to achieve something similar to this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Stack;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class TypeLocator {

    private final JsonNode outerNode;
    private static TypeLocator _instance;
    private final JsonNode root;

    // Default constructor to get the content and store in the root
    private TypeLocator() throws IOException {
        // Create the jackson instance and get the JSON Schema Information
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        root = mapper.readTree(TypeLocator.class.getClassLoader().getResource("JSON-Schema.json"));
        outerNode = root.path("definitions");
    }

    // Method to create a Object instance of current class
    private static synchronized TypeLocator getInstance() throws IOException {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new TypeLocator();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    // Method called by other application to get the element Type
    public static Optional<String> locate(List<String> elementPath) throws IOException {


        // Get the JSON Schema information
        TypeLocator cl = getInstance();
        JsonNode rootNode = cl.outerNode;

        // Check if there are element and obtain the event type info
        final String eventType = elementPath.get(0).substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + elementPath.get(0).substring(1);
        final JsonNode eventInfo = rootNode.get(eventType);
        elementPath.remove(0);
        if (elementPath.size() > 0) {

            // Loop through elements in particular event Type and get type
            for (JsonNode allOf : eventInfo) {
                for (JsonNode allElements : allOf) {
                    Optional<String> type = recurse(allElements, new Stack<String>(), elementPath);
                    if (type.isPresent()) {
                        return type;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();

    }

    private static Optional<String> recurse(JsonNode node, Stack<String> elements, List<String> elementPath) {

        // Check if its Reference type
        if (node.get("$ref") != null) {
            // Check if the element has reference to other definition
            final String ref = node.toString().contains("definitions") ? node.get("$ref").toString().replace("\"", "").replaceAll("#/definitions/",
                                "") : null;

            // Check if the Reference is null
            if (ref != null) {
                final JsonNode refElements = _instance.outerNode.get(ref);
                return recurse(refElements, elements, elementPath);
            }
        } else if (node.get("items") != null && elementPath.size() > 0) {
            // Check if the element has Array type with items
            final String ref = node.get("items").toString().contains("definitions") ? node.get("items").get("$ref").toString().replace("\"", "")
                                .replaceAll("#/definitions/", "") : null;
            if (elementPath.size() > 0 && elementPath.get(0).equals(ref)) {
                elementPath.remove(0);
                final JsonNode refElements = _instance.outerNode.get(ref);
                return recurse(refElements, elements, elementPath);
            }
        } else if (node.get("properties") != null && elementPath.size() > 0) {
            // Check if the element has properties if no recurse through properties
            final JsonNode prop = node.get("properties");

            if (elementPath.size() > 0 && prop.get(elementPath.get(0)) != null) {
                final JsonNode elementInfo = prop.path(elementPath.get(0));
                elementPath.remove(0);
                return recurse(elementInfo, elements, elementPath);
            }
        } else if (node.path("type") != null && elementPath.size() == 0) {
            // If the element has type then return the final Type
            return Optional.of(node.get("type").toString());
        } else {
            // If the element is not found then directly check
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```